# how to check (null) for string

Tags: c#, string, null

I have a parser that returns string value as (null)

Here is the screenshot of value from IDE

[image: null is the empty]

```
if(mystr!="(null)"){

}
```

This condition also becomes true and thats strange because the condition is supposed to fail.

so how to compare for this value any idea

Comment: Don't use the string null for comparison, use the keyword null. The null keyword is a literal that represents a null reference. Also, you can use the method, ```String.IsNullOrEmpty```, reads nice

Comment: Not clear, what are you asking for.

Comment: `if (mystr != null)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use literal **null**? Use keyword `null`.

Comment: But its not null.. its (null) thats why I am confused

Comment: @Ranjithkumar: And what happens when you *actually try* to use the keyword `null`?  Does your code *actually fail* in any way?

Comment: The IDE displays null values as `(null)`. That's just how your ID is designed. An actual string of containing `(null)` will be displayed as `"(null)"`, probably. @Ranjithkumar

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string is null, try use:

```
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(mystr))
```

or

```
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mystr))
```